# dynaimcally encapsulate data in multiple form tags

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So I have a page that dynamically populates mysql data depending on how many entries meet the sql query conditions.

So if 10 entries are displayed after querying the DB, there are 10 sets of data, each with its unique table id in a hidden input, all visually separated with fieldset tags, and so 10 `update entry` buttons at the bottom of each fieldset so the user can click the button if any data in a particular fieldset section is altered.

Is it possible to encapsulate the data in each fieldset in form tags as well so the data enclosed can be updated in the DB if altered by the user?

Comment: _Is it possible to encapsulate the data in each fieldset in form tags as well so the data enclosed can be updated in the DB if altered by the user?_ - **Yes**, it definitely possible